# Read .ini file vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, ini

I have one project with function to read .ini files. I can not display the contents of .ini file that I want to.

My code to read .ini file

```
Public Function GetSettingItem(ByVal File As String, ByVal Identifier As String) As String
    Dim S As New IO.StreamReader(File) : Dim Result As String = ""
    Do While (S.Peek <> -1)
        Dim Line As String = S.ReadLine
        If Line.ToLower.StartsWith(Identifier.ToLower & "=") Then
            Result = Line.Substring(Identifier.Length + 2)
        End If
    Loop
    Return Result
End Function
```

My code to load code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label1.Text = GetSettingItem("D:\WorldInfo.ini", "Count")
    Label2.Text = GetSettingItem("D:\WorldInfo.ini", "Count")
 End Sub
```

my .ini files

```
[B_Empty_IndexList]
Count=2
00_Th=0
01_Th=1
[B_Use_IndexList]
Count=0
00_Th=-1
01_Th=-1
```

in my project i wanna load information Count from [B_Empty_IndexList] to Label1 and Count from [B_Use_IndexList] to Label2 .. but when i use my code Label1 and Label2 just load Count from [B_Use_IndexList]

Anyone help me how to read ini file to load information

```
Label1 -> Load Information Count from [B_Empty_IndexList]
Label2 -> Load Information Count from [B_Use_IndecList]
```

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 8):

There is no point rolling your own method to do this. Use the Windows API method GetPrivateProfileString to do it:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

<DllImport("kernel32")>
Private Shared Function GetPrivateProfileString(ByVal section As String, ByVal key As String, ByVal def As String, ByVal retVal As StringBuilder, ByVal size As Integer, ByVal filePath As String) As Integer
End Function

Public Function GetIniValue(section As String, key As String, filename As String, Optional defaultValue As String = "") As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder(500)
    If GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, defaultValue, sb, sb.Capacity, filename) > 0 Then
        Return sb.ToString
    Else
        Return defaultValue
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Debug.WriteLine(GetIniValue("B_Empty_IndexList", "Count", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\WorldInfo.ini"))
    Debug.WriteLine(GetIniValue("B_Use_IndexList", "Count", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\WorldInfo.ini"))
End Sub
```

Note some background reading if using this approach: [Could there be encoding-related problems when storing unicode strings in ini files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976372/could-there-be-encoding-related-problems-when-storing-unicode-strings-in-ini-fil)

Answer (score 3):

Those suggested Windows API have been deprecated for a long time now and they are really bad, you see on each GetPrivateProfile call you are reading and parsing the INI content all over again...

As an alternative try using my MadMilkman.Ini library, like this:

```
Imports MadMilkman.Ini

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ini As New IniFile()
    ini.Load("D:\WorldInfo.ini")

    Label1.Text = ini.Sections("B_Empty_IndexList").Keys("Count").Value
    Label2.Text = ini.Sections("B_Use_IndecList").Keys("Count").Value
End Sub
```

You can download the library from here: https://github.com/MarioZ/MadMilkman.Ini

**EDIT**
I was asked to elaborate more the discussion that I had with IInspectable in the comments below.
*IInspectable: "Your solution doesn't appear to account for surrogate pairs."*
*Mario Z: "I have no idea why you assume that library doesn't support Unicode, it does and its quite simple... just use the appropriate encoding."*

So here it goes, in short .NET's String represents an array of Chars and Char represents 16-bit character. When faced with a string that contains a 32-bit character it will use a so called "surrogate pair" (two characters that represent one). Now when working with this kind of string an issue that can happen for example is that we can make an invalid substring of that string if we cut it in the middle of that "surrogate pair". Also another issue that can happen is when working with the string indexer and not taking into account that a "surrogate pair" will consist of two indexed chars in that string.

However that is all not the case with MadMilkman.Ini, the library directly manipulates only with a specific set of characters while the rest of the string is left as it is (string is a self-consistent type with a full Unicode support). The characters that are targeted and manipulated are [, ], =, etc.

As an example here is a writing test sample:

```
Dim textWithSurrogatePairs =
    "sample content " + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(Int32.Parse("22222", NumberStyles.HexNumber))

Dim ini = New IniFile(
    New IniOptions() With {.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode})

ini.Sections.Add(
    New IniSection(ini, "sample section",
        New IniKey(ini, "sample key", textWithSurrogatePairs)))

ini.Save("sample file.ini")
```

The following is the content of "textWithSurrogatePairs" variable:

[image]

The following is the generated output "sample file.ini" file:

[image]

Also here is reading test sample:

```
Dim ini = New IniFile(
    New IniOptions() With {.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode})

ini.Load("sample file.ini")

Dim readValue = ini.Sections("sample section").Keys("sample key").Value
```

The following is the "readValue" variable:

[image]

So in short the .NET framework itself handles the surrogate pairs, the only thing that we need to be aware of is to use an appropriate Encoding (as shown above).
Unfortunately this is something that IInspectable fails to realize and I failed to properly explain to him.

Comment: How is it superior than using a system-provided service (that has been tested on billions of installations over decades)? It needs to be a lot better to justify a dependency. Also, it is very well received to state your affiliation with an off-site resource, when you post a link to it. Likewise, link-only answers are not very well received (this essentially being one).

Comment: @IInspectable I believe in my first sentence I explained one of the advantages of this approach, but there are quite a few more, if you're truly interested I can list them for you.

Regarding your statement about decades of testing, what are you talking about?
There are literally hundreds of known bugs and limitations on the internet regarding the GetPrivateProfile methods (for example even Matt mentioned one in his answer).Also the MS itself does not recommend it, from their documentation:
"Note: This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit Windows-based applications."

Comment: @IInspectable Regarding my affiliation, I apologize, I should have mentioned its my library, I have edited the answer.

Last regarding the link-only answers, again what are you talking about?
I've provided a complete snippet code with which he can achieve his task, yes it's that simple, few lines and you're done.

Comment: Your snippet is useless, should the off-site resource become unavailable. This is essentially a link-only answer. As you point out, there are issues with the GetPrivateProfileXxx APIs. As you also point out, those are **known** issues. Your library has **unknown** issues. Plus, you have not really answered the question: How is the library superior? Calling something *"really bad"* is not a very concise problem description, and being better than really bad is not exactly a sign of superiority.

Comment: IInspectable seriously think about what are you saying here... I mean have you ever in your entire carrier used an external library or a control and thus eliminated the need of reinventing the wheel? From your statement it seems like you haven't... Stackoverflow is full of the answers that provide library to OP's requirements, that is a very natural thing in programming... I mean common do we really need to discussion about this? For starters have you heard of the NuGet? That should answer your question about unavailability.

Comment: Also regarding the unknown issue, I've covered my library with a lot of unit and regression tests, that is the best that anyone can provide but if someone encounters an issue I'm their to help them out and to resolve that, common man that is just a common sense to provide a technical support for your open source projects.

Comment: Now regarding the superiority, first the known issues with those APIs do not occur in this solution, second it was designed for .NET developers and for them it's very intuitive (API is similar to existing .NET's FCL), third it provides quite a few additional features, fourth it reads and parses the file from the disk only once while those APIs accesses and parses the file on each call. Also the most important thing is, as I already mentioned **these Windows API are not recommended nor supported by MS** so if you encounter a bug (regardless of is it a known or unknown) it will not be resolved.

Comment: IInspectable that is a last thing I have to say about this subject, the OP will choose whatever approach he wants, but I don't want to have further discussion with you because I feel like you are ignoring most of the things I write and also it seems to me you have some knowledge gaps in this area which I don't intent to fill them out for you.

Comment: No idea, why you assume that those Windows APIs are *"not supported by MS"*. Of course they are. If a security critical bug is discovered, it **will** get fixed. And if you need a specific feature, you can file a *Design Change Request* with Microsoft. Microsoft then decides, based on certain criteria (like business impact), whether the request will be met. The age of an API is not one of those criteria. As for superiority: Your solution doesn't appear to account for surrogate pairs. At all. In other words: Your library doesn't do Unicode.

Comment: I have no idea why you assume that library doesn't support Unicode, it does and its quite simple... just use the appropriate encoding. Also it is obvious that its not supported because there are known issues which are not being addressed for ages. The reason is quite simple, ini files have a successor, config files.

Comment: Also the fact is that there is no way a new feature will be added to something that is strictly defined as not recommended.

Comment: I am not assuming, I have verified that it doesn't. Coming up with a surrogate pair that causes your lib to fail is pretty easy (and left as an exercise to the author). The fact that certain known issues aren't being addressed is fairly simple: Once a bug is shipped it is propagated to a feature. Software out in the wild is relying on it. Little leeway for the owner to change things. This is no indication, that the API is not supported.

Comment: As I mentioned before it does support Unicode and it's actually quite easy, you can find a working sample under the ReadUTF8EncodingTest and WriteUTF8EncodingTest. If you check them out I believe you will find what you did wrong. Nevertheless I see from your profile that you are actually not familiar with .NET environment, there is nothing to be ashamed of, if you need help you can just ask and I’ll gladly provide it.

Comment: Also unfortunately your assumptions are wrong, the ini bugs did not propagated into a feature. Actually what happened is (and this is a rather common thing) the API is obsoleted because it was not able to meet the requirements. The API is left as it is to maintain backward compatibility, with now a very old systems, and then another API (actually another format) was provided as a recommended successor.

Comment: You haven't answer my question, also yes you can put this more direct... can you explain how I may reproduce your issue so that I can investigate it? Also can you name where I use char? Common men seriously look at what you wrote and tell me that it is not ambiguous. Also I would encourage you to be polite, there is no need for that kind of language and "threats".

Comment: Also I really encourage you to investigate the library and report any issue that you find, if I can reproduce them I’ll be more than happy to resolve them. You do understand that this is an open source project, I have no profit from it, just a pure enjoyment of being able to help others achieve these kind of tasks with ease.

Comment: can't find translate `"My code " & varcode & "!"` can use  `mycode=My code %d!` ?

Comment: @ITVlogs Try: `Dim file As New IniFile()` `file.Sections("sample").Keys("mycode").Value = "My code " & varcode & "!"` `file.Save("sample.ini")`

Answer (score 1):

Example ini file:

```
[MAIN]
Setting_1=something
```

a. Create a class clsINI

```
Public Class clsIni
' API functions
Private Declare Ansi Function GetPrivateProfileString _
  Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" _
  (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
  ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpDefault As String, _
  ByVal lpReturnedString As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
  ByVal nSize As Integer, ByVal lpFileName As String) _
  As Integer
Private Declare Ansi Function WritePrivateProfileString _
  Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" _
  (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
  ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpString As String, _
  ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
Private Declare Ansi Function GetPrivateProfileInt _
  Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetPrivateProfileIntA" _
  (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
  ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal nDefault As Integer, _
  ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
Private Declare Ansi Function FlushPrivateProfileString _
  Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" _
  (ByVal lpApplicationName As Integer, _
  ByVal lpKeyName As Integer, ByVal lpString As Integer, _
  ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
Dim strFilename As String

' Constructor, accepting a filename
Public Sub New(ByVal Filename As String)
    strFilename = Filename
End Sub

' Read-only filename property
ReadOnly Property FileName() As String
    Get
        Return strFilename
    End Get
End Property

Public Function GetString(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As String) As String
    ' Returns a string from your INI file
    Dim intCharCount As Integer
    Dim objResult As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256)
    intCharCount = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, [Default], objResult, objResult.Capacity, strFilename)
    If intCharCount > 0 Then
        GetString = Left(objResult.ToString, intCharCount)
    Else
        GetString = ""
    End If

End Function

Public Function GetInteger(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As Integer) As Integer
    ' Returns an integer from your INI file
    Return GetPrivateProfileInt(Section, Key, _
       [Default], strFilename)
End Function

Public Function GetBoolean(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As Boolean) As Boolean
    ' Returns a boolean from your INI file
    Return (GetPrivateProfileInt(Section, Key, _
       CInt([Default]), strFilename) = 1)
End Function

Public Sub WriteString(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As String)
    ' Writes a string to your INI file
    WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, strFilename)
    Flush()
End Sub

Public Sub WriteInteger(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As Integer)
    ' Writes an integer to your INI file
    WriteString(Section, Key, CStr(Value))
    Flush()
End Sub

Public Sub WriteBoolean(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As Boolean)
    ' Writes a boolean to your INI file
    WriteString(Section, Key, CStr(CInt(Value)))
    Flush()
End Sub

Private Sub Flush()
    ' Stores all the cached changes to your INI file
    FlushPrivateProfileString(0, 0, 0, strFilename)
End Sub
End Class
```

b. Instantiate the class:

```
Dim objIniFile As New clsIni(path_of_your_file)
```

c. Get the setting:

```
Dim x As String
x = objIniFile.GetString("MAIN", "Setting_1", "")
```

d. Update / Create a setting:

```
objIniFile.WriteString("MAIN", "Setting_1", "new_setting")
```

Edit:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim objIniFile As New clsIni("D:\WorldInfo.ini")
    Label1.Text = objIniFile.GetString("B_Empty_IndexList", "Count", "")
    Label2.Text = objIniFile.GetString("B_Use_IndexList", "Count", "")
End Sub
```

Comment: If .ini file like above how?

Comment: @AndrePabertiyan, I edited my answer and put the code at the bottom for you.

Comment: @3dd, can you please explain why my answer is badly formatted?

Comment: @DanielGee Thanks bro it's work and i can finish my project thank you very much

Comment: The PrivateProfile APIs are horrible, slow, quirky legacy calls that should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @AlexK: When you suggest to stop using a particular system service, you will have to provide an alternative. It's also fairly unclear, why you mention the quirky nature in a comment to an answer, that already deals with the quirks, and hides them behind a clean interface. As for the API being slow, you'd have to have an insanely huge INI file for that to even begin to matter.

Comment: For 1 thing, instantiating a class with no retention value is overhead and poor design.  At the very least, they should be Shared functions to read/write.  Furthermore, the best place for something like this would be in a helper module of some kind, since there is no reason to have reference to a class to use it.  The filename can be passed in with Section and Key if need be, no need to hold it in a Property of a class that has no retention value.  We can go on.