# VB.Net read file content

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make an simple program to message box the executable that runs in `"autorun.inf"`

example:

```
[Autorun]
open=setup.exe
icon=setup.exe,0
```

how do i define the line which says
even if it's not the second line, it could be the 5th, i mean after some text..

```
open=setup.exe
```

and trim the file name and it's extension?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read .ini file vb.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402503/read-ini-file-vb-net). Autorun.inf is in INI file format (a section name bracketed by [], and name=value pairs under that section), and Windows has API routines to deal with those types of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim FilePath As String = "E:\run.inf"
    Dim INF As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(FilePath)
    INF = INF.ToLower
    Dim StartIndex As Integer = INF.IndexOf("open=") + 5
    Dim EndIndex As Integer = INF.IndexOf(vbCrLf, StartIndex)
    Dim ExecutableName As String = ""

    If StartIndex = 4 Then
        MsgBox("the executable file name could not found at file :" & vbCrLf & FilePath)
    Else
        If EndIndex = -1 Then
            ExecutableName = INF.Substring(StartIndex)
        Else
            ExecutableName = INF.Substring(StartIndex, EndIndex - StartIndex)
        End If
        MsgBox("The Executable Name is " & Chr(34) & ExecutableName & Chr(34))
    End If
```

first we read all the text of the INF file and change its case to lower so that we can search through it for lower `"open="`.
and then we define the start index and the end index of the executable name as the start after string `"open="` and the end before the newline `vbCrlf`.
and finally get Executable Name and show it in a `MsgBox`.