# Auto load TabControl from settings.ini file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

I want when start form auto load TabControl TabPages from in ini file settings with WebBrowser1. I added image to below.

settings.ini file

```
[site1]
name=Google
url=https://www.google.com

[site2]
name=Yahoo
url=https://www.yahoo.com
```

clsINI class code

```
Public Class clsIni
' API functions
Private Declare Ansi Function GetPrivateProfileString _
  Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" _
  (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
  ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpDefault As String, _
  ByVal lpReturnedString As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
  ByVal nSize As Integer, ByVal lpFileName As String) _
  As Integer
Private Declare Ansi Function WritePrivateProfileString _
  Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" _
  (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
  ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpString As String, _
  ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
Private Declare Ansi Function GetPrivateProfileInt _
  Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetPrivateProfileIntA" _
  (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
  ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal nDefault As Integer, _
  ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
Private Declare Ansi Function FlushPrivateProfileString _
  Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" _
  (ByVal lpApplicationName As Integer, _
  ByVal lpKeyName As Integer, ByVal lpString As Integer, _
  ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
Dim strFilename As String

' Constructor, accepting a filename
Public Sub New(ByVal Filename As String)
    strFilename = Filename
End Sub

' Read-only filename property
ReadOnly Property FileName() As String
    Get
        Return strFilename
    End Get
End Property

Public Function GetString(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As String) As String
    ' Returns a string from your INI file
    Dim intCharCount As Integer
    Dim objResult As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256)
    intCharCount = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, [Default], objResult, objResult.Capacity, strFilename)
    If intCharCount > 0 Then
        GetString = Left(objResult.ToString, intCharCount)
    Else
        GetString = ""
    End If

End Function

Public Function GetInteger(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As Integer) As Integer
    ' Returns an integer from your INI file
    Return GetPrivateProfileInt(Section, Key, _
       [Default], strFilename)
End Function

Public Function GetBoolean(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As Boolean) As Boolean
    ' Returns a boolean from your INI file
    Return (GetPrivateProfileInt(Section, Key, _
       CInt([Default]), strFilename) = 1)
End Function

Public Sub WriteString(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As String)
    ' Writes a string to your INI file
    WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, strFilename)
    Flush()
End Sub

Public Sub WriteInteger(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As Integer)
    ' Writes an integer to your INI file
    WriteString(Section, Key, CStr(Value))
    Flush()
End Sub

Public Sub WriteBoolean(ByVal Section As String, _
  ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As Boolean)
    ' Writes a boolean to your INI file
    WriteString(Section, Key, CStr(CInt(Value)))
    Flush()
End Sub

Private Sub Flush()
    ' Stores all the cached changes to your INI file
    FlushPrivateProfileString(0, 0, 0, strFilename)
End Sub
End Class
```

It's new tabcontrol code but without loop, i couldn't make it here.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim tb As TabControl = New TabControl
        Dim page1 As TabPage = New TabPage
        tb.TabPages.Add(page1)
        Me.Controls.Add(tb)
        tb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

    End Sub
End Class
```

And i want like this, help me please..
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyPHu.png)

Comment: Figure out how to loop through the INI file first.  Then just put your code into the loop (except the creating of the main TabControl).  Add in the creation of the WebBrowser control and set it to DockStyle.Fill like you did with the TabPage.  Update us with your progress...

Comment: Have a code please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found solution for question...

[Click for clsINI reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31405069/7586300)

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim LoadSettings As New clsIni("C:\settings.ini")
        Dim sites As String
        Dim url As String

        Dim array() As Integer = {1, 2, 3}

        Dim tb As TabControl = New TabControl

        For i As Integer = 1 To array.Length - 1

            sites = LoadSettings.GetString("site" & i, "name", "")
            url = LoadSettings.GetString("site" & i, "url", "")

            Dim page As TabPage = New TabPage
            Dim browser As WebBrowser = New WebBrowser

            tb.TabPages.Add(page)
            page.Text = sites

            Me.Controls.Add(tb)
            tb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

            page.Controls.Add(browser)
            browser.Navigate(url)
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```